# gRPC and HTTP Status Codes - why is it always http 200?

Tags: json, http, protocol-buffers, grpc

When working with gRPC, I see that if we use http codes (because I am told we don't technically need to), that we always return http 200.

I understand grpc has its own mapping for response code, but my question is why by design are http codes not part of gRPC? What were the trade offs in doing this / advantages?

Comment: You should still handle HTTP errors, for example 404, 500, 503. HTTP is the transport and something can go wrong in the transport